# Can Beat Cop be discarded during another player’s turn?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Can Beat Cop’s free triggered ability be used during **any** player window to incur 1 damage to an enemy at its location, even a player window occurring during another investigator’s turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. *Any* player can use free actions, like the Beat Cop's ability, during *any* player window, including during another player's turn.

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c4/b0/c4b0d66c-d79e-411b-bdb5-b5d8c457d4bc/ahc01_rules_reference_web.pdf).

> Free triggered abilities ([free action symbol (squiggle)] triggered ability  may be triggered as a player ability during any player window.

and

> The red boxes are player windows. Players may use [free action symbol] triggered abilities in these windows.

See pages 23 and 26 of the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c4/b0/c4b0d66c-d79e-411b-bdb5-b5d8c457d4bc/ahc01_rules_reference_web.pdf) for the timing of the player windows.